# bigbluebutton Unauthorized Session not found. 401

Tags: xml, api, vps, bigbluebutton

hello I am trying to use bigbluebutton I installed it and I am trying to join a meeting but I get the error Unauthorized Session not found. 401 I am not using any code yet just API

```
<response>
<returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
<messageKey>successfullyJoined</messageKey>
<message>You have joined successfully.</message>
<meeting_id>645b8fbaef16c732ce0d5d1b18e228ae871a51ce-1665354247961</meeting_id>
<user_id>w_yimip2runuko</user_id>
<auth_token>7wgto8qpdu07</auth_token>
<session_token>tsdknt1oozvo17ev</session_token>
<guestStatus>ALLOW</guestStatus>
<url>http://178.79.155.44/html5client/join?sessionToken=tsdknt1oozvo17ev</url>
</response>
```

this is the response but when I use the link it get me the error

I am trying to join in my computer browser not in the server side

Comment: there are a few issues here, when you join a meeting, the meeting must be running, so first you create a meeting but if no one joins the meeting before a certain time elapses the meeting will end, so its a good idea to check the meeting is running https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/dev/api.html#ismeetingrunning

Comment: If the meeting is running then you need to create a  "join" "url",  which will redirect you to the html5 client, unless as it seems in this case you have set the "redirect" query parameter in your join "url" to false,  suggest try steps, 1 create, 2 ismeetingrunning, 3 join with redirect = true

Answer (score 0):

When calling the Api related to Create, set the value of the allowRequestsWithoutSession parameter to true and consider the other two parameters related to time as a large value.
In the next step, call the method related to Join the meeting.
for create:

```
allowRequestsWithoutSession=true
meetingExpireIfNoUserJoinedInMinutes=2000
meetingExpireWhenLastUserLeftInMinutes=360
```

Api create:

> https://X.com/bigbluebutton/api/create?name=titile&meetingID=3ddce9f2-6414-4585-87e4-8fecb71ff226&allowRequestsWithoutSession=true&meetingExpireIfNoUserJoinedInMinutes=2000&meetingExpireWhenLastUserLeftInMinutes=360&checksum=YYY

Join Api:

> https://X.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?role=MODERATOR&fullName=ahmad&userID=20&redirect=false&meetingID=0b8354fa-f0d2-4238-a1c2-254386693b7e&checksum=YYY

Copy url tag to Browser. it is ok . :)